# Prevent worker role recycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, iis, azure-worker-roles

I have an Azure Worker role that downloads images and rescales them. If the worker role is really busy my solution recycles quite often. I think it is IIS restarting the role because of the high CPU or high error exception rate (the download can receive a 404 exception which is handled by the way).

1. How can I find out what the cause of recycling is? I added a the following code but does not give me a lot of information:

```
public void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Find out why the application ends
    var reason = HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason;
    LogException("Application.End", "Hosted Service: " + CwPlatform.HostedServiceName
        + ", ShutdownReason:" + Enum.GetName(typeof(ApplicationShutdownReason), reason), 
        ExceptionLevel.Critical);
}
```

2. Is there a way of preventing IIS to recycle because of this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me You get it wrong. Worker role “Does not use IIS, and runs your app standalone”

Comment: There are many situations that will cause IIS to recycle such as an ISAPI deciding it's unhealthy, any module crashing, idle timeout. In order to avoid IIS recycling we can disable Idle timeouts, disable Regular time interval. For more information about it, you can refer to this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/333907/what-should-i-do-to-make-sure-that-iis-does-not-recycle-my-application